# Pandas 2 dataframes into one graph

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 separate dataframes that look exactly the same but with different numbers in it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clip emotes':[79,223,435,291,188,99,153,50,55,78,83,48,43,73]}, index=['roohappy','rooblank','lul','omegalul','pog','pogchamp','roovv','roowut','roopog','pepehands','biblethumb','roocry','rooree','rooblind'])
df
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vod emotes':[3963,7286,5560,4390,3386,3111,2639,2612,2422,1999,1948,1691,1654,1573,1308,1090,1024,1019,1019,974,945,912,893,856,790,771,731,677,658,652]}, index=['rood','roovv','pepega','lul','clap','rookek','roocult','rooblank','pog','rooree','rooaww','roohappy','omegaroll','rooduck','rooh','rareroo','roocry','pepehand','lulw','rooderp','roopog','hyperclap','roospy','rooayaya','omegalul','roolove','roowut','roonya','monkas','roo4'])
df
```

and then I do `df.plot(kind = 'bar')` for both of the separately. I cant figure out how can I put these two datas into a one graph one over the other so that one bar with the same name would be over the other with a different colour.

Comment: A stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining them:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'clip emotes':[79,223,435,291,188,99,153,50,55,78,83,48,43,73]}, index=['roohappy','rooblank','lul','omegalul','pog','pogchamp','roovv','roowut','roopog','pepehands','biblethumb','roocry','rooree','rooblind'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vod emotes':[3963,7286,5560,4390,3386,3111,2639,2612,2422,1999,1948,1691,1654,1573,1308,1090,1024,1019,1019,974,945,912,893,856,790,771,731,677,658,652]}, index=['rood','roovv','pepega','lul','clap','rookek','roocult','rooblank','pog','rooree','rooaww','roohappy','omegaroll','rooduck','rooh','rareroo','roocry','pepehand','lulw','rooderp','roopog','hyperclap','roospy','rooayaya','omegalul','roolove','roowut','roonya','monkas','roo4'])

df3 = df2.join(df1)
df3.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Stacked bar chart]